# How to delete the selected option using title attribute of select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I want to delete the first option of the selected and I  have selected tag id and class but the problem is selected class and id is changing when I open the form of different-2 event.and **class "r"** of selected tag is using more than one time different-3 drop down of form.

I want to remove the selected option using title attribute of selected tag.

If any other way to resolved this type of problem please share.

```
<select name="DROPDOWN_735" class="r" id="DROPDOWN_735" title="State*">
  <option value="">Select One </option>
  <option value="Michigan"> Michigan</option>
  <option value="Alabama"> Alabama</option>
  <option value="Alaska"> Alaska</option>
  <option value="Arizona"> Arizona</option>
  <option value="Arkansas"> Arkansas</option>
  <option value="California"> California</option>
  <option value="Colorado"> Colorado</option>
  <option value="Connecticut"> Connecticut</option>
  <option value="Delaware"> Delaware</option>
  <option value="Florida"> Florida</option>
  <option value="Georgia"> Georgia</option>
</select>
```

I want to delete

```
<option value="">Select One </option>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `I open the form of different-2 event`

Comment: means one form is using for the so many events and when i open form for different-different events id and name change automatically

Comment: because form is generated using plugin

Comment: So you cannot use select.r ?

Comment: yes i cant because i am using two dropdown list on a form and both are using same class

Comment: Both have same title?

Comment: no title is different

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127160/discussion-between-shahzad-ditro-and-mplungjan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to select using class and title in plain JavaScript

```js
window.onload=function() {
  var sel = document.querySelector("select.r[title='State*']");
  console.log(sel);
  sel.options[0]=null;
}
```

```html
<select name="DROPDOWN_735" class="r" id="DROPDOWN_735" title="State*">
  <option>Please select State</option>  
  <option>option 1</option>
</select>  
<select name="DROPDOWN_735" class="r" id="DROPDOWN_735" title="NotState*">
  <option>Please select Not State</option>  
  <option>option 1</option>
</select>
```

Ditto in jQuery

```js
$(function() {
  var $options = $("select.r[title='State*'] option");
  $options.eq(0).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="DROPDOWN_735" class="r" id="DROPDOWN_735" title="State*">
  <option>Please select State</option>  
  <option>option 1</option>
</select>  
<select name="DROPDOWN_735" class="r" id="DROPDOWN_735" title="NotState*">
  <option>Please select Not State</option>  
  <option>option 1</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add the hidden attribute:

```
<option value="" hidden>Select One</option>
```

this will result in being the default selected value but you can't select it in the dropdown

**Example:**

```html
<select name="DROPDOWN_735" class="r" id="DROPDOWN_735" title="State*">
  <option value="" hidden>Select One</option>
  <option value="Michigan">Michigan</option>
  <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
  <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
  <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
  <option value="Arkansas">Arkansas</option>
  <option value="California">California</option>
  <option value="Colorado">Colorado</option>
  <option value="Connecticut">Connecticut</option>
  <option value="Delaware">Delaware</option>
  <option value="Florida">Florida</option>
  <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
</select>
```

> The hidden attribute can also be used to keep a user from seeing an element until some other condition has been met (like selecting a checkbox, etc.).
>
> The hidden attribute is new in HTML5.

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_hidden.asp

Comment: Did you even try this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option

Comment: On what browsers? Please post snippet. I have not seen a `hidden` property of an option element

Comment: Shows `Select one` in my Chrome and IE and Firefox

Comment: @mplungjan: But if you pick another one, you can't pick it back again.

Comment: @mplungjan it shows select one as default but you can't select it

Comment: hidden is a global html5 property check here for more information: [hidden property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden)

Comment: Yeah, I found it. I see the effect now, but it does not trigger until after the change. Interesting attribute but does not work as requested here. I did remove my downvote though

Comment: Also not supported by IE8

Comment: We make sure that our sites looks good for the most browsers, but IE8 we ignore since 2015 :)  It seems the last version to consider is IE11 -> [caniuse.com/#search=hidden](http://caniuse.com/#search=hidden)

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario if select box's id is changing dynamically then you can achieve this with it's class name like below

```
$(".r option[value='']").each(function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

If you want to delete it by using ID then you can do it like this..

```
$("#DROPDOWN_735 option[value='']").each(function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Or

```
$("select option[value='']").each(function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select[title='State*'] option:first-child[value='']").remove();
})
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<select name="DROPDOWN_735" class="r" id="DROPDOWN_735" title="State*">
  <option value="">Select One </option>
  <option value="Michigan"> Michigan</option>
  <option value="Alabama"> Alabama</option>
  <option value="Alaska"> Alaska</option>
  <option value="Arizona"> Arizona</option>
  <option value="Arkansas"> Arkansas</option>
  <option value="California"> California</option>
  <option value="Colorado"> Colorado</option>
  <option value="Connecticut"> Connecticut</option>
  <option value="Delaware"> Delaware</option>
  <option value="Florida"> Florida</option>
  <option value="Georgia"> Georgia</option>
</select> 

<select name="DROPDOWN_735" class="r" id="DROPDOWN_735" title="State*">
  <option value="">Select One </option>
  <option value="Michigan"> Michigan</option>
  <option value="Alabama"> Alabama</option>
  <option value="Alaska"> Alaska</option>
  <option value="Arizona"> Arizona</option>
  <option value="Arkansas"> Arkansas</option>
  <option value="California"> California</option>
  <option value="Colorado"> Colorado</option>
  <option value="Connecticut"> Connecticut</option>
  <option value="Delaware"> Delaware</option>
  <option value="Florida"> Florida</option>
  <option value="Georgia"> Georgia</option>
</select>
```

Hope it will be useful.

Comment: That will remove it from any select that has an empty value

Comment: @mplungjan I just updated it. I will remove first option with empty value